# Android Fragment onCreateView with Gestures

Tags: android

I'm attempting to utilize Gestures within a fragment; I have the following inside of a FragmentActivity which handles my details fragment.  What I am attempting to have happen is when a swipe is detected on the view to replace the data inside of that view with the previous or next entry.

If there is a better way of handling this; I am all for it.  However, what is happening here is that the onFling method is never actually called.

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {

                    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                    try {
                        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                            return false;
                        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Right to Left");
                        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Left to Right");
                            titles.showDetails(getPosition() - 1);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }
            });

        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looks like the following issue explains this: [Android: GestureDetector won't catch Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027553/android-gesturedetector-wont-catch-gestures)

Additionally here is the result:

The solution is actually to Override the onDown method and return true; otherwise the gesture detector will stop and not detect the up:

```
        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {
                    Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "onFling has been called!");
                    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                    try {
                        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                            return false;
                        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Right to Left");
                        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Left to Right");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }
            });

        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Comment: just curious: why isn't the reference to gesture lost?

Comment: @LemLordjeKo why would the reference to `gesture` be lost? `gesture` is held as a reference by the `View.OnTouchListener` we created, and that is held as a reference by the view itself, `v`. Java is mature enough, if there is a path to an object, it almost certainly won't get GC'd.

Comment: The following imports are needed for the above snippet to work:


import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.util.Log;

class Constants {
    public static final String APP_TAG = "mytag";
}

Answer (score 9):

a couple comments

1. I had to tweak my code as follows:

   ```
   v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override        
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           // return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);

           gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
           return true; // <-- this line made the difference
       }
   });
   ```
2. Also, if you are using an xml file to create your view

   ```
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
   ```

make sure you are actually pressing the intended view. A nice way to exaggerate the test is to make both the width and the height to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content" in your layout xml file.

Comment: I missed that @mwillbanks overrides onDown to return true for the SimpleOnGestureListener. I only implemented on onSingleTapConfirmed and onDoubleTap.