# GestureDetector on Fragment with TabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, swipe, gesturedetector

I need to change tabs in a FragmentTabHost on swipe. Each of the tabs in the TabHost actually shows another fragment. I used some of the code showed here: [Android Fragment onCreateView with Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421368/android-fragment-oncreateview-with-gestures) but it doesn't seem to work with my scenario.

```
public class OpenedGlimpsedMenuDrawer extends Fragment  {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

//Mandatory Constructor
public OpenedGlimpsedMenuDrawer() {
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_fragment_menudrawer,container, false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Opened").setIndicator("Opened"),
            OpenedFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Glimpsed").setIndicator("Glimpsed"),
            GlimpsedFragment.class, null);

    final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.i("FLING IS CALLED!!", "OnDown Method");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {

                    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                    try {
                        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                            return false;
                        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.i("FLING IS CALLED!!", "Right to Left");
                            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                            Log.i("FLING IS CALLED!!", "Left to Right");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }
            });

        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you check [this][1] code? Also use fragment inside GestureDetector.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421565/900338