# How to use gesture detector in Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, swipe-gesture, gesturedetector

I have class (MainActivity.java) with extends Activity, in the inside i declare Fragment class (FragmentShow.java) . I tried use GestureDetector in Fragment class, but this gesture not working, if I use GestureDetector in Activity class is working.
The question is how to use GestureDetector in fragment class?

Thanks.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.getActivity().onTouchEvent(event);
}

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    super.getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public class MyGestureListener extends
        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    // handle 'swipe left' action only

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {
            Utils.log("Swipe left - startActivity()");

        } else {
            Utils.log("Swipe Right - startActivity()");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This I call Fragment from MainActivity

```
FragmentDashboard hello = new FragmentDashboard();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, hello)
                .commit();
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Please refer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421565/3527886

Comment: public class MyGestureListener extends
   GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
    float velocityX, float velocityY) {

   /*
    * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), event1.toString() + "\n\n"
    * +event2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    *

   if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {
    Utils.log("Swipe left - startActivity()");

   } else {
    Utils.log("Swipe Right - startActivity()");}
   return true;}}

Comment: Show the code containing your fragment class

Comment: Hi Mayur Patel , I can't resolve my problem with your refer

Comment: ojonugwa ochalifu, I call fragment with this

FragmentDashboard hello = new FragmentDashboard();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.fragment_container, hello)
  .commit();

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: If you want fast help, you need to post questions that are easy to understand.Right now, you are posting your classes together. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer/33096003#33096003) question I posted to get an idea of how to format your questions.Don't be in a rush

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Sorry if my question is difficult to understand, but here I need answers , not questioning my question . Thx

Comment: That's the attitude, keep it up.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421368/android-fragment-oncreateview-with-gestures). It has the answer this question has asked.