# Change fragment on horizontal scroll?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

In my app I use Android JetPack navigation component, I created some fragments in one activity each open on button click. Is it possible to add in one fragment ViewPager which scroll to second but other fragments in this activity will open with button?

Comment: I found solution. I just use SimpleOnGestureListener and in method onFling Navigation.findNavController() to change fragment

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sollution here: [Android Fragment onCreateView with Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421368/android-fragment-oncreateview-with-gestures?rq=1)
Here my code, on right to left swipe navigate to other fragment

```
final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
        Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "onFling has been called!");
        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

               Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.YOURFRAGMENTID);

            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
});

v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
}
});
```

Put this in the onCreateView() method of the fragment.